# how to write a sorted function in python for version before 2.4

Tags: python

I am unfortunately having to use python with version before 2.4 So I don't have the `sorted` built-in function. I need to sort a list; I found it is not possibly to go with

```
for aName in mylist.sort(lambda x,y:cmp(x.getName,y.getName)):
```

because then I would get an error saying

`TypeError: iteration over non-sequence`

I want to do the following:

```
for aName in sorted(mylist,key=lambda x:x.getName):
```

Can anybody help me with this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that you wanted to do `for aName in sorted(mylist,key=lambda x:x.getName):` but accepted an answer that did something else ...

It's quite possible to write code that will run on multiple versions of Python 2.x. Here's how to retrofit `sorted()` functionality to Python 2.1 to 2.3. It uses the DSU (decorate-sort-undecorate) aka "Schwartzian Transform" method ... see [this section of the Sorting HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/sorting.html#the-old-way-using-decorate-sort-undecorate) but do read the whole HOWTO; it's *very* informative.

```
try:
    sorted
    def mysorted(iterable, key, reverse=0):
        return sorted(iterable, key=key, reverse=reverse)
except NameError: # doesn't have "sorted"
    def mysorted(iterable, key, reverse=0):
        temp = [(key(x), x) for x in iterable]
        temp.sort()
        if reverse:
            return [temp[i][1] for i in xrange(len(temp) - 1, -1, -1)]
        return [t[1] for t in temp]

mylist = 'tom dick harriet alfred zechariah'.split()
mykey = lambda x: x[2:] # ignore 1st 2 characters
print mylist
print mysorted(mylist, mykey)
print mysorted(mylist, mykey, reverse=1)
```

Running the above script with Python 2.7.1 and 2.1.3 produces the same output:

```
['tom', 'dick', 'harriet', 'alfred', 'zechariah']
['zechariah', 'dick', 'alfred', 'tom', 'harriet']
['harriet', 'tom', 'alfred', 'dick', 'zechariah']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist.sort(lambda x,y:cmp(x.getName,y.getName))
for aName in mylist:
  ...
```

`list.sort` sorts in-place and doesn't have return value.

Comment: I think the OP needs to review the "mutable" section of Python.

Comment: -1 Provides neither `sorted` nor `key` -- i.e. functionality restricted to **slow** `cmp` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sorted(iter, **rest):
    temp = list(iter)
    temp.sort(**rest)
    return temp
```

I think that should work.

Comment: -1 The OP wants it to run on Pythons before 2.4, whose `sort()` doesn't accept keyword args, and doesn't have a `key` arg. Don't think; instead, read the manual and test your code.